# Rename or move field data from a custom field to the 'body' field?

Tags: entities, nodes

Once upon a time, when I was young and not very bright, I created a content type for a site.

In my ultimate wisdom, I deleted the default body field saying "I'll never need this!" and created a new textarea with a machine name that followed some conventions I was using at that time.

Several years and 60,000+ nodes of that content type later, the site is still running. However, any Views/Panels are a pain in the @ss to build since every other content type I've created since conveniently still has the default 'body' field, but this one (which has most of my content of course), does not.

How can I either A) rename my "my_story_body" field to be the default "body" field for a content type -OR- recreate the default "body" field and copy all the content from the field "my_story_body" into the proper field?

I will be testing the following tonight on a dev version of my database:

```
drush php-eval '$types = node_type_get_types(); node_add_body_field($types[“my-article-type], $label="Body");'
```

Hopefully that will recreate the default 'body' type I deleted, leaving me to only have to solve copying data from one field to another.

Running D7.31.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Running D7.31_. Erm.... https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005

Comment: Thanks for the concern. 7.32 is on the dev server, still having our integrations tested. Any ideas with the original question?

Comment: I don't have time to write it out but your approach of using `node_add_body_field()` is best IMO. Basically you want a batch job that loads up the nodes (`node_load_multiple()`), copies the data from `$node->field_story_board` to `$node->body` (they're just arrays so nothing special from Drupal's perspective), then saves each node. After that you can remove the old field from the content type, run `field_purge_batch()` a bunch of times to clear up, and you should be golden.